# Change css-module dynamically on React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a canvas like this in Component

It can change the pointer to `crosshair` when cursor is entered on Canvas.

```
import styles from '../css/basic-styles.module.css';

const ImagePreview = () =>{
    [mode,setMode] = useState(0);
    changeMode(mode){
       setMode(mode);
    }
    return (){
        <canvas className={styles.canvas} width=200 height=200></canvas>
    }
}
```

in css

```
canvas:hover{
  /*cursor:pointer;*/
  cursor:crosshair;
}
```

Now I want to change the css dynamically depending on the `mode` value.

I want to use `pointer` when mode is 1

I should quite use `css`? or is there any method to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the solution below. It is also available in the [sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-tdd-4qblsp?file=/src/App.js:58-380). Ignore the vanilla react solution it included for the snippet runner. Click `Run Code Snippet` to see preview here.

```js
/* Solution

const ImagePreview = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(0);
  return (
    <canvas
      onMouseEnter={() => setMode(1)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setMode(0)}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "teal",
        cursor: mode ? "crosshair" : "pointer"
      }}
      width={200}
      height={200}
    />
  );
};

*/

// This is so it can work in Stackoverflow snippet preview. //
const ImagePreview = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState(0);
  const canvasCfg = {
    onMouseEnter: () => setMode(1),
    onMouseLeave: () => setMode(0),
     style: { backgroundColor: "teal", cursor: mode ? "crosshair" : "pointer"},
     width: 200,
     height: 200
  }
  return React.createElement('canvas', canvasCfg)
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(React.createElement(ImagePreview));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create two classes like this

```
canvas1:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}


canvas2:hover{
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

and use it conditionally based on mode like

```
import styles from '../css/basic-styles.module.css';

const ImagePreview = () =>{
    [mode,setMode] = useState(0);
    changeMode(mode){
       setMode(mode);
    }
    return (){
        <canvas className={mode == 1 ? styles.canvas1 : styles.canvas2} width=200 height=200></canvas>
    }
}
```

you can also use classes without `:hover` , this will also give the desired result because of cursor property

```
.canvas1{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.canvas2{
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```